# IntegerUpDown triggering parent control SelectionChanged event

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, integerupdown

I have a ListBox control with IntegerUpDown in each ListBoxItem.  Everything works fine, but when the IntegerUpDown reaches the min or the max I set, If I click on the disabled arrows it'll trigger a selectionchanged event for the listbox.
[Disabled arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvkFe.png)

```
private void lbItem_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{    
     if (//e.source != integerupdowncontrol)
         //update other view, etc.  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hooking into the selectionchanged event, checking for your disabled condition, and if disabled set the `SelectionChangedEventArgs.Handled` to `true`?

[SelectionChangedEventArgs MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args){
      if(/*My min or max has been reached*/){
            args.Handled = true;
            return;
      }
}
```

Here is another [example with keypressed](http://www.dotnetperls.com/previewkeydown)

Comment: How would I check if the selectionchanged event came from the IntegerUpDown control though? Both Source and OriginalSource are pointing to listbox. Unless I know the event originated from the IntegerUpDown I can't handle it.

Comment: Well unless you post your code I can't really provide any further details @sponge

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding a MouseLeftButtonDown event for the IntegerUpDown in which I set Handled = true. It feels "hackish" though.